# Calling a one to many list in a saved entity returns null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I check an entities contents right after saving it, everything appears normal, but any other time and the mapped entities in it are all null. Both checks are done by getting it through its repository.

**Ad**

```
package com.stevan.madsapp.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "ad")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "ad.getAds",
        procedureName = "get_ads",
        parameters = { @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "param1", type = String.class) }
)
public class Ad {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ad")
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author")
    private UserDetails author;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_details_ad",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_details_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ad_id")
    )
    private Set<UserDetails> usersFinished = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job")
    private Job job;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public UserDetails getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(UserDetails author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Set<UserDetails> getUsersFinished() {
        return usersFinished;
    }

    public void setUsersFinished(Set<UserDetails> usersFinished) {
        this.usersFinished = usersFinished;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }
}
```

**Question**

```
package com.stevan.madsapp.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String question;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<McOption> radioOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<McOption> checkboxOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ad_id")
    private Ad ad;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public List<McOption> getRadioOptions() {
        return radioOptions;
    }

    public void setRadioOptions(List<McOption> radioOptions) {
        this.radioOptions = radioOptions;
    }

    public List<McOption> getCheckboxOptions() {
        return checkboxOptions;
    }

    public void setCheckboxOptions(List<McOption> checkboxOptions) {
        this.checkboxOptions = checkboxOptions;
    }
}
```

**AdService**

```
package com.stevan.madsapp.services;

import com.stevan.madsapp.entities.*;
import com.stevan.madsapp.repositories.AdRepository;
import com.stevan.madsapp.security.components.TokenIdCheck;
import com.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.AdDTO;
import com.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.QuestionDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class AdService {

    @Autowired
    private AdRepository adRepository;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public List<AdDTO> getAds(Integer id)
    {
        UserDetails user = userDetailsService.getUserDetails(id);
        Job job = user.getJob();
        Country country = user.getCountry();

        List<Ad> jobAds = job.getAds();
        List<Ad> countryAds = country.getAds();
        List<Ad> commonAds = new ArrayList<Ad>(jobAds);
        commonAds.retainAll(countryAds);

        return convertListToDTO(commonAds);
    }

    public Ad store(AdDTO ad, Integer id) {
        Ad newAd = new Ad();
        newAd.setName(ad.getName());

        List<Question> newQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Question question : ad.getQuestions())
        {
            Question newQuestion = questionService.store(question);
            newQuestions.add(newQuestion);
        }

        newAd.setQuestions(newQuestions);
        newAd.setAuthor(userDetailsService.getUserDetails(id));
        newAd.setJob(jobService.getJob(ad.getJobId()));
        newAd.setCountry(countryService.getCountry(ad.getCountryId()));

        adRepository.save(newAd);
        System.out.println(adRepository.getById(newAd.getId()).getQuestions());
        return newAd;
    }

    public Ad getAd(Integer id)
    {
        return adRepository.getById(id);
    }

    public AdDTO requestAd(Integer adId, Integer userId)
    {
        Ad ad = getAd(adId);
        UserDetails user = userDetailsService.getUserDetails(userId);
        if(ad.getJob() != user.getJob() || ad.getCountry() != user.getCountry())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return convertToDTO(ad);
    }

    public List<AdDTO> convertListToDTO(List<Ad> ads)
    {
        List<AdDTO> adDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Ad ad: ads)
        {
            AdDTO newAdDTO = convertToDTO(ad);
            adDTOS.add(newAdDTO);
        }
        return adDTOS;
    }

    public AdDTO convertToDTO(Ad ad)
    {
        AdDTO newAdDTO = new AdDTO();
        newAdDTO.setId(ad.getId());
        newAdDTO.setName(ad.getName());
        newAdDTO.setQuestions(ad.getQuestions());
        newAdDTO.setJobId(ad.getJob().getId());
        newAdDTO.setCountryId(ad.getCountry().getId());
        return newAdDTO;
    }
}
```

**QuestionService**

```
package com.stevan.madsapp.services;
import com.stevan.madsapp.entities.Ad;
import com.stevan.madsapp.entities.McOption;
import com.stevan.madsapp.entities.Question;
import com.stevan.madsapp.repositories.QuestionRepository;
import com.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.McOptionDTO;
import com.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.QuestionDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private McOptionService mcOptionService;

    public Question store(Question question)
    {
        Question newQuestion = new Question();
        newQuestion.setQuestion(question.getQuestion());
        newQuestion.setType(question.getType());
        if (newQuestion.getType().equals("radio"))
        {
            List<McOption> newMcOptions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (McOption mcOption : question.getRadioOptions())
            {
                McOption newMcOption = mcOptionService.store(mcOption);
                newMcOptions.add(newMcOption);
            }
            newQuestion.setRadioOptions(newMcOptions);
        }
        else if(newQuestion.getType().equals("checkbox"))
        {
            List<McOption> newMcOptions = new ArrayList<McOption>();
            for (McOption mcOption : question.getCheckboxOptions())
            {
                McOption newMcOption = mcOptionService.store(mcOption);
                newMcOptions.add(newMcOption);
            }
            newQuestion.setCheckboxOptions(newMcOptions);
        }
        questionRepository.save(newQuestion);
        return newQuestion;
    }
}
```

(This one just in case I missed something)
**AdController**

```
package com.stevan.madsapp.web.controllers;

import com.stevan.madsapp.entities.Ad;
import com.stevan.madsapp.exceptions.ValidationException;
import com.stevan.madsapp.security.components.TokenIdCheck;
import com.stevan.madsapp.services.AdService;
import com.stevan.madsapp.validators.AdValidator;
import com.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.AdDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/forms", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class AdController {

    @Autowired
    private AdService adService;

    @Autowired
    private AdValidator adValidator;

    @Autowired
    private TokenIdCheck tokenIdCheck;



    @GetMapping(value = "/statuscheck")
    private ResponseEntity<Object> check()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    private ResponseEntity<List<AdDTO>> getAllAds(@RequestHeader("id") Integer id)
    {
        List<AdDTO> adList = adService.getAds(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(adList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/request")
    private ResponseEntity<AdDTO> getAd(@RequestHeader("adId") Integer adId,
                                        @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
                                        @RequestHeader("id") Integer id)
    {
        if(tokenIdCheck.check(id, token))
        {
            AdDTO adDTO = adService.requestAd(adId, id);
            if(adDTO != null)
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(adDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @PostMapping
    private ResponseEntity<AdDTO> uploadAd(@RequestBody AdDTO adDTO,
                                        @RequestHeader("id") Integer id) throws ValidationException
    {
        Errors optionalErrors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(adDTO, "adDTO");
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(adValidator, adDTO, optionalErrors);

        if(optionalErrors.hasErrors())
        {
            throw new ValidationException(optionalErrors);
        }
        Ad newAd = adService.store(adDTO, id);
        return newAd != null
                ? new ResponseEntity<>(adService.convertToDTO(newAd), HttpStatus.OK)
                : new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

To clarify more thouroughly now, when I sysout an Ads questions, right after I store it, it shows that it has some questions, but when I do it when requesting an Ad later, it shows an empty list. In mysql they have their apropriate foreign keys.

Comment: There's a procedure called get_ads on your Ad entity, I presume your repository ia using It to retrieve the Ads, right? If so, take a look at it and what query It is executing, maybe It is not fetching the questions in this procedure. This is Just a guess

Comment: @FelipeBonfante It thought fetching the parent entity will bring along the mapped ones. There is a getAd() method below, which uses an integrated JPA repository method, should that normally work?

Comment: Can you provide your AdRepository? What I was saying is that on your entity Ad there is an annotation called @NamedStoredProcedureQuery pointing to an procedure called get_ads and maybe that's what is being used to retrieve your Ads, and this would be a custom query not using jpa at all, and It would not fetch parente automatically If you can provide the adRepository we can check If that IS the case

Comment: @FelipeBonfante Oh I was just experimenting with those, I'm not using that query. I'm only using the methods below. Is there any reasons why those wouldn't fetch the questions. Or maybe why would they only fetch the questions immediately after saving the Ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to save the ad_id in the Question entity before I added that question to the questions_id list in the Ad entity. The only problem I had with that is that in order to set the parent Ad as the ad_id in every question, I needed to save the Ad itself first.
Here are the changes:

In AdService:

```
public Ad store(AdDTO ad, Integer id) {
    Ad newAd = new Ad();
    newAd.setName(ad.getName());
    newAd.setAuthor(userDetailsService.getUserDetails(id));
    newAd.setJob(jobService.getJob(ad.getJobId()));
    newAd.setCountry(countryService.getCountry(ad.getCountryId()));
    adRepository.save(newAd);
    Set<Question> newQuestions = newAd.getQuestions();
    for(Question question : ad.getQuestions())
    {
        Question newQuestion = questionService.store(question, newAd);
        newQuestions.add(newQuestion);
    }

    adRepository.save(newAd);
    System.out.println(adRepository.getById(newAd.getId()).getQuestions());
    return newAd;
}
```

I just added another adRepository.save(newAd) before cycling through questions, and changed the store Question method to take in an Ad, which I used to set the ad_id in questions.

and in QuestionService:

```
public Question store(Question question, Ad newAd)
{
    Question newQuestion = new Question();
    newQuestion.setQuestion(question.getQuestion());
    newQuestion.setType(question.getType());
    newQuestion.setAd(newAd);
    if (newQuestion.getType().equals("radio"))
    {
        List<McOption> newMcOptions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (McOption mcOption : question.getRadioOptions())
        {
            McOption newMcOption = mcOptionService.store(mcOption);
            newMcOptions.add(newMcOption);
        }
        newQuestion.setRadioOptions(newMcOptions);
    }
    else if(newQuestion.getType().equals("checkbox"))
    {
        List<McOption> newMcOptions = new ArrayList<McOption>();
        for (McOption mcOption : question.getCheckboxOptions())
        {
            McOption newMcOption = mcOptionService.store(mcOption);
            newMcOptions.add(newMcOption);
        }
        newQuestion.setCheckboxOptions(newMcOptions);
    }
    questionRepository.save(newQuestion);
    return newQuestion;
}
```